# TYPO3 does not autoload PHP files in Classes folder

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, autoload

Hi I started working with TYPO3 a few weeks ago and I wanted to run my own PHP script when the website starts. So I put my PHP file called "Testfile.php" into typo3conf/ext/myextension/Classes folder. My code:

```
namespace Example\MyExtension;


class Testfile
  {
       public function doStuff() {
       return 'I did stuff';
       }
  }
```

After that I put this typoscript code into my page at the backend.

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = USER
page.10.userFunc = Example\MyExtension\Testfile->doStuff
```

After refreshing my page I expected to get the text "I did stuff" but got only a blanc screen.

Can you explain me what I did wrong?

Comment: `page.10.userFunc` does not look like PHP?

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 do you use? Do you use composer?

Comment: this also looks wrong? `Example\MyExtension\Testfile->doStuff` You didn't instantiate it by saying `$x = new\Example\MyExtension\Testfile(); $x->doStuff();`

Comment: TYPO3 V9.5 with composer

Comment: The `page.10.` etc. stuff is TYPO3 TypoScript setup and the syntax is correct.

Comment: In addition to the 2 answers, which are probably correct, a blank screen usually means an error. The error itself should be logged in your log files. If the answers are indeed correct it's probably something like `Class "Example\MyExtension\Testfile" not found`, but if it's something different it might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare autoloading instructions in composer.json and did you fire `composer du` or other that would regenerate the class loader files?

Answer (score 0):

For own extensions that are not required by composer you have to add the base of your extension classes to the autoload section of the composer.json in your root path, e.g.

`"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        Example\\MyExtension\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Classes",
    }
}`

After that call `composer dumpautoload` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in composer mode ???

In composer mode adding the autoload part in composer.json as Chris described above should work, but if you are note in composer mode I don't know how you can add php code since includeLibs is gone

Answer (score 0):

Declare "autoload" in you composer then run `composer dumpautoload`

Goodluck